# Particular integral for $a\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+b\frac{dy}{dx}+cy=\ln x$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to know how to find a particular integral for $$a\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+b\frac{dy}{dx}+cy=\ln x$$
where $a,b,c$ are constants. So far, the only functions I've come across for $f(x)$ in
$$a\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+b\frac{dy}{dx}+cy=f(x)$$
are $$f(x)=x^ne^{kx}$$ $$f(x)=A\sin\alpha x+B\cos\alpha x$$ $$f(x)=\text{polynomial in $x$ with positive integer exponents}$$
and the particular integrals I've been taught to use respectively  are $$x^ne^{kx}+x^{n-1}e^{kx}+\cdots+e^{kx}$$ $$y=C\sin\alpha x+D\cos\alpha x$$ $$y=\text{polynomial in $x$ with positive integer exponents of the same degree as $f(x)$}$$ unless complications arise when finding the complimentary function.

However, how do I find the particular integral for when $f(x)=\ln x$?

Comment: You will need the [Wronskian](https://www.math24.net/second-order-linear-nonhomogeneous-differential-equations-variable-coefficients/).

Comment: Unfortunately, $\ln x$ is not one of the functions where the method of undetermined coefficients works.  So some other method is needed.  ODE textbooks should discuss variation of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

*Here's a trick*

For a linear, second-order, constant-coefficient ODE, with arbitrary function $h(x)$,
\begin{align}
a\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}+b\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}+cy=h(x)
\end{align}
making the substitution
\begin{align}
z(x)=\delta y(x)+\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx},
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\delta =\left(\frac{b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)
\end{align}
reduces the order of your ODE:
\begin{align}
a\frac{\mathrm dz}{\mathrm dx}+\frac{c}{\delta}z(x)=h(x).
\end{align}
I think you can take it from there.